# Bootstrap Alert Size Change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alert

Is there a way I could edit how far an alert could stretch across the page, so it doesn't go all the way across?

Here's an example of my alerts:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">Your first number was correct.</div>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Using some `CSS`

```
.alert {
   width:40%;    
}
```

Example

http://www.bootply.com/96921

The example above makes the alert width 40% of the container, or in this case the screen.

You can also set a fixed width.

```
.alert {
   width:300px;    
}
```

Comment: Modifying the percentages above didn't work for me in the example provided; however modifying the alert to a fixed-width did.

Comment: Is modifying height possible? I tried setting height w/ percentage and setting by px only works to an extent

Answer (score 34):

if you want that the alert is juste the size of the inner text :

```
.alert {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Currently you could use `d-inline-block` class

Comment: d-inline in bootstrap, thanks!!

Answer (score 19):

Placing it in a `row` and offsetting its `col` did it for me.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="alert alert-danger col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" align="center">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the Accepted Answer!

Comment: I found that just surrounding with <div class="row"> auto scaled the alert to fit snugly around the message. Didn't need to add the col definitions. I don't know if this is because I am using Bootstrap v4 or not.

Comment: There is too much to deal with using this approach (especially on mobile screens) compared to just setting it to inline-block

Comment: @shinzou What on earth. Why would no one use Bootstrap in 2019? Bulma and others are nice but that doesn't make Bootstrap bad.

Comment: Much better solution. I don't think people realize that writing raw CSS is the absolute last resort when you use a CSS framework. It makes the code incredibly difficult to maintain when devs do it too much

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of Bootstrap (v4 and v5), you can use this simple width modifier (`w-25`, `w-50`, `w-75`):

```
<div class="alert alert-danger w-50" role="alert">
  You have been altered, dangerously!
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/

Answer (score 3):

I think it would work to just take the code from the question

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
```

and add one of the column classes like this

```
<div class="alert alert-success col-md-3">
```

Something like that worked for me anyhow, my exact code was

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible col-md-3" role="alert">
```

Made a nice small alert out of it just a bit bigger than a button.

Answer (score 1):

If your alert is part of a `.row` then setting its class to include `.col-lg-12` will force it to span across its container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4.0 or above your can make use of `d-inline-block`.

Here is an example how to use it:

```
<div class="alert alert-success d-inline-block" role="alert">
    This is a success alert—check it out!
</div>
```

In bootstrap's documentation you can read more about the [display property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `span` instead of a `div`. It is again the same "inline vs block elements" dilemma.

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="alert alert-info">div alert</div>
<span class="alert alert-info">span alert</span>
```

Available since, at least, bootstrap v3.